# Can I limit force pushes to the GitHub actions user only?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have two protected branches `main` and `main-nightly`.

Every evening at 11PM I want to create a PR from `main-nightly` into `main` and merge it if checks succeed.

Now before that, I need to update (rebase) `main-nightly` onto `main` and push changes back into the branch. Since the branch is protected though I cannot push.

Is the GitHub actions user (GITHUB_TOKEN) allowed to force push? If not, can I only enable that user to be allowed to force push to the branch?